# Fetching large data from node using Gottox/socket.io-java-client

Tags: java, javascript, android, node.js, sockets

I am using Gottox/socket.io-java-client to fetch data from Node.

If i fetch data from Local server, or http server it do not create any problem,
in fetching any amount of data at a time, however when the connection is https then 
Gottox/socket.io-java-client is not able to fetch data from Node. I am not getting any exception also.

To fetch the same amount of data from node using socket.io javascript library, works fine in all three cases. 
Code used in fetching data from node in Javascript is

```
    Socket.prototype.getChatHistory = function(myChatid){

    try{
    Buttler.lsocket.emit('getChatHistory', {chatid:myChatid}, function(content)
    {   

    }catch(e){
        alert("Emit Error :"+e);
        }
}
```

The data i am fetching contains images and text.

Code used in fetching data from Node using java is

```
 try {
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

   json.putOpt("chatid", string);
   json.putOpt("userid", userID);

   // IOAcknowledge ack=null;

   IOAcknowledge ack = new IOAcknowledge() {
    @Override
    public void ack(Object... args) {
     if (args.length > 0) {
      Log.v("chatHistory:Acknowledgement:", "chatHistory:DON:"
        );

      // callBack.gotChatHistoryCallBack(args[0].toString());
      new ParseChatHistoryAsyncTask(c, args[0].toString())
        .execute(chatType,args[0].toString());

     }
    }
   };

   socket.emit("getChatHistory", ack, json);
   //socket.emit("getChatHistoryEvent",  json);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I am not able to find out why the problem is coming while fetching data from in https connection from node in java